# RequireJS in combination with Drupal 7 Javascripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7, requirejs

I'm currently using RequireJS for a web app. This web app is made available through a module in a Drupal 7 site. The site's functionality is dependent on a number of Javascripts which is included in each page, for example jQuery and some of Drupal's core scripts from the misc folder. The web app is too.

Drupal produces its own list of Javascripts to include through script tags in the headers of the HTML as such (please note this is only a shortened list):

```
<script src="http://localhost/match/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery/1.8/jquery.js?v=1.8.2"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/match/misc/drupal.js"></script>
```

Drupal also exports settings like this:

```
<script>jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, {"basePath":"\/\/","pathPrefix":"","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"bootstrap","theme_token":"SFe43uIfGphkyHT8v49IX8ad5j3RyHAeb6qEjsBmDMc","js":{"sites\/all\/modules\/jquery_update\/replace\/jquery\/1.8\/jquery.js":1,"misc\/jquery.once.js":1,"misc\/drupal.js":1,"sit... etc </script>
```

Currently, I have my require.js script inclusion as the last script to include in the HTML header.

In my web app I want to use the global Drupal object and its settings, thus I have a dependency on it while it is not loaded via requirejs. Also, jQuery is used in my web app and is also being included by the Drupal CMS itself.

Only one part of the Drupal site is providing the web app to end users. The rest is just plain old Drupal doing its thing.

What is the best practice to handle this situation?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Does the site work? That seems like an adequate solution for a site that doesn't use requirejs for a lot of its functionality. You *could* use `paths`, etc, to integrate the other script with requirejs, but as long as you know how the app works (and can document it for yourself) then what you have already seems fine to me.

Comment: The site works. The app works. The point is that I don't want to run into a situation where a dependency isn't there due to asynchronous loading issues. AFAIK Javascripts load synchronously when linked using <script> tags, so I should be fine. I just want to make sure I'm choosing the right path.

Comment: Yep that's right. <script> tags will load sync unless you dynamically add them to the page or use the async or defer attrs. Good write up here - http://peter.sh/experiments/asynchronous-and-deferred-javascript-execution-explained/. If you find you need to juggle your scripts around then you might have to start loading some of your existing scripts as modules, which might involve you having to patch them for AMD.